# Java - best option to select callable method at runtime by argument class

Tags: java

This is example of some service processing object of different classes:

```
class SomeService {
  void method(A a) {
    /* A class logic here */
  }

  void method(B b) {
    /* B class logic here */
  }

  ...

  void method(Z z) {
    /* Z class logic here */
  }

  public <T> void method(T anyClass) {
    /* Some heavy common logic here */      

    /* (1) Here I want to call method corresponding class of   
       "anyClass" parameter */
  }
}
```

I would like to call only `method(T anyClass)` in other components. What is the best option to select and call one of private methods in (1)

Comment: You can have `if (anyClass instanceof A) method((A) anyClass);` ... but I'm not sure what you think you're getting out of using generics in that case.

Comment: What kind of logic is in `method(A a)` and `method(B b)`?

Comment: Why? Overload resolution would do this. Adding the generic method doesn't change anything for the caller.

Comment: ```instanceof``` is probably the best option.  But I have a lot of types to process, so it ends in 30 ```if``` statements, I think there is more elegant solution.

Comment: Honestly I'm trying to emulate compile-time templates in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be quite close to Startegy design pattern.

**Strategy design pattern definition** (source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

> In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the
>   policy pattern) is a software design pattern that enables an
>   algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime. The strategy pattern
>
> - defines a family of algorithms,
> - encapsulates each algorithm, and
> - makes the algorithms interchangeable within that family.

Comment: This is an option, but I have to create something like ```Map<Class<?>, Consumer<?>>``` to get strategy pattern here. I'm looking for more elegant soution. Something similar to compile-time templates in C++.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar with C++. Also do you mean `Map<Class<A>, Consumer<A>>` or `Map<Class<A>, Consumer<B>>` ?

Comment: I have methods for different classes. So I must use wildcard to be able to do something like ```methods.get(value.getClass())).accept((T) value);``` where ```methods``` is map storing references to service methods for specifed classes (also there is possible class cast Exception). I did something like this once and it ended up with a lot of references, so I'm looking for more elegant solution now.

Comment: I meant the wildcards are from 2 different types or from the same type ?

Comment: They ment to be the same, but wildcard are always any class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to utilise the MBassador event bus, as a disclaimer I will say that this is probably not the *best* way to do this, although it will work. Once a class has subscribed to the bus, a "message" (can be a standard class) can be sent to the bus using `publish()`. The event bus will use the `@Handler` annotation to find listener methods. The type of parameter the listener message expects will enable the bus to choose the correct method to call.

In this example `Class1` and `Class2` are empty classes, that both extend an empty abstract class called `AbstractClass`

**Example Main Class**

```
import net.engio.mbassy.bus.MBassador;
import net.engio.mbassy.bus.config.BusConfiguration;

public class SomeService
{
    private static MBassador<AbstractClass> bus;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Creates the bus, and passes that  instance of the 
        //bus into the Methods class
        bus = new MBassador<>(BusConfiguration.Default());
        Methods methodsClass = new Methods(bus);

        sendMessage(new Class1());
        sendMessage(new Class2());
    }

    //This is equivalent to your method(T anyClass)
    public static void sendMessage(AbstractClass anyClass)
    {
        //Do common logic

        SomeService.bus.publish(anyClass);
    }
}
```

**Class that contains individual methods**

```
import net.engio.mbassy.bus.MBassador;
import net.engio.mbassy.listener.Handler;

public class Methods
{
    MBassador<AbstractClass> bus;

    public Methods(MBassador<AbstractClass> busIn)
    {
        //Subscribe to the bus, so that you can listen to 
        //messages that are published onto it
        this.bus = busIn;
        this.bus.subscribe(this);
    }


    //Class specific methods, called by the bus
    //due to the message published in SomeService.sendMessage()

    @Handler (rejectSubtypes = false)
    public void doThing(Class1 cl)
    {
        System.out.println("Class 1");
    }

    @Handler (rejectSubtypes = false)
    public void doThing(Class2 cl)
    {
        System.out.println("Class 2");
    }
}
```

In this case the console output is

Class 1

Class 2

Hope this helps, feel free to ask for any clarification in the comments